# Scraping recursively with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to create a scrapy script with the intent on gaining information on individual posts on the medium website. 
Now, unfortunately, it requires 3 depths of links. Each year link, and each month within that year and then each day within the months links.

I've got as far as managing to get each individual link for every year, every month in that year and every day. However I just can't seem to get scrapy to deal with the individual day pages.

I'm not entirely sure whether I'm confusing using rules and using functions with callbacks to get the links. There isn't much guidance on how to recursively deal with this type of pagination. I've tried using functions and response.follow by itself without being able to get it to run.

The parse_item function dictionary is required because several articles on the individual day pages have several different ways of classifying the title annoyingly. So i created a function to grab the title regardless of the actual XPATH needed to grab the title.

The last function get_tag is needed because on each individual article that is where the tags are to grab.

I'd appreciate any insight into how to get the last step and getting the individual links to go through the parse_item function, the shell o. I should say there are no obvious errors than I can see in the shell.

Any further information necessary just let me know.

Thanks!

**CODE:**

```
import scrapy
from medium.items import MediumItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
class DataSpider(CrawlSpider):
     name = 'data'
     allowed_domains = ['medium.com']
     start_urls = ['https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/']
     rules = (
         Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
              allow=(),
                restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="timebucket u-inlineBlock u-width50"]/a')), follow=True, callback='years'),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=(),
                restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="timebucket u-inlineBlock u-width80"]/a')), follow=True, callback='months' ),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=(),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="timebucket u-inlineBlock u-width35"]/a')),callback='days'
                ))

def years(self,response):
    for year in response.xpath('//div[@class="timebucket u-inlineBlock u-width50"]/a/@href').extract():
        yield response.follow(year, callback=self.months)

def months(self,response):
    for month in response.xpath('//div[@class="timebucket u-inlineBlock u-width50"]/a/@href').extract():
        yield response.follow(month,callback=self.days)

def days(self,response):
    for day in response.xpath('//div[@class="timebucket u-inlineBlock u-width35"]/a/@href').extract():
        yield response.follow(day,callback=self.parse_item)



def parse_item(self,response):
    dic = {}
    dic['title1'] = 'h3[@class="graf graf--h3 graf-after--figure graf--title"]/text()'
    dic['title2'] = 'h3[@class="graf graf--h3 graf-after--figure graf--trailing graf--title"]/text()'
    dic['title3'] = 'h3[@class="graf graf--h3 graf-after--h4 graf--trailing graf--title"]/text()'
    dic['title4'] = 'h3[@class="graf graf--h3 graf--leading graf--title"]/text()'
    dic['title5'] = 'h3[@class="graf graf--h3 graf-after--figure graf--title"]/span[@class="markup--anchor markup--h3-anchor"]/text()'
    dic['title6'] = 'h3[@class="graf graf--h3 graf-after--h3 graf--trailing"]/text()'


    articles = response.xpath('//div[@class="postArticle postArticle--short js-postArticle js-trackPostPresentation js-trackPostScrolls"]')
    def title(dict, articles):
        for article in articles:
            for num in dic.keys():
                if article.xpath('.//' + dic.get(f'{num}')).extract_first() == None:
                    continue
                else:
                    title = article.xpath('.//' + dic.get(f'{num}')).extract_first()
            return title

    for article in articles:
            item = MediumItem()

            item['date'] = article.css('time::text').extract_first() + ' 2019'
            item['read'] = article.css("span::attr(title)").extract_first()
            item['publication'] = article.xpath('.//a[@class="ds-link ds-link--styleSubtle link--darken link--accent u-accentColor--textNormal"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['name'] = article.xpath('.//a[@class="ds-link ds-link--styleSubtle link link--darken link--accent u-accentColor--textNormal u-accentColor--textDarken"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['claps'] = article.xpath('.//button[@class="button button--chromeless u-baseColor--buttonNormal js-multirecommendCountButton u-disablePointerEvents"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['responses'] = article.xpath('.//a[@class="button button--chromeless u-baseColor--buttonNormal"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['text'] = title(dict,articles)

            yield item


            link = article.xpath('.//a[@class="link link--darken"]/@href').extract_first()
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.get_link, meta={'item':item})


def get_tag(self,response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['tag'] = response.css("ul > li > a::text").getall()
        yield item
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2020-02-06 16:56:38 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 
NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
2020-02-06 16:56:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
  https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/2019/03/04> (referer: 
 https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/2019/03) ['cached']
 2020-02-06 16:56:38 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 
NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
2020-02-06 16:56:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
 https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/2019/03/03> (referer: 
  https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/2019/03) ['cached']
  2020-02-06 16:56:38 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 
 (Windows  NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36
  2020-02-06 16:56:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
  https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/2019/03/02> (referer: 
  https://medium.com/tag/python/archive/2019/03) ['cached']
  2020-02-06 16:56:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
  2020-02-06 16:56:38 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
  {'downloader/request_bytes': 1236771,
  'downloader/request_count': 1984,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1984,
'downloader/response_bytes': 137377143,
'downloader/response_count': 1984,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1984,
  'dupefilter/filtered': 52095,
  'elapsed_time_seconds': 76.366135,
   'finish_reason': 'finished',
   'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 6, 16, 56, 38, 573687),
  'httpcache/hit': 1984,
  'log_count/DEBUG': 3970,
   'log_count/INFO': 11,
   'log_count/WARNING': 45,
   'request_depth_max': 4,
  'response_received_count': 1984,
  'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
  'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
  'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
  'scheduler/dequeued': 1983,
  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1983,
   'scheduler/enqueued': 1983,
  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1983,
  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 6, 16, 55, 22, 207552)}
  2020-02-06 16:56:38 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: remove the three functions `years`,`months`,`days` no need for them at all, in the rule with the days xpath `callback='parse_item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the three functions years,months,days

```
rules = (
         Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="timebucket u-inlineBlock u-width50"]/a')),),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(

                restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="timebucket u-inlineBlock u-width80"]/a')), ),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(follow=True,
                restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="timebucket u-inlineBlock u-width35"]/a')),callback='parse_item'
                ))

def parse_item(self,response):
    #your code,
```